# Error using reticulate in RStudio Cloud: AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'Chart'

Tags: python, r, altair, reticulate

I am trying to create a plot with Altair in a RMarkdown in RStudio Cloud but it seems that it is not finding the functions of the package.

This is how I set up the environment using reticulate:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("test-reticulate")
py_install("pandas", envname = "test-reticulate")
py_install("altair", envname = "test-reticulate")
use_virtualenv("test-reticulate")
```
````

This is the python code to create the plot:

````
```{python}
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)

```
````

When I run it I get the following message:

```
Python 3.6.12 (/home/rstudio-user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python)
Reticulate 1.18 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'Chart'
```

Not sure if this makes a difference but when I look at the path it does not point to the environment "test-reticulate" I created inside "project":

```
>>> alt.__path__
_NamespacePath(['/cloud/project/altair', '/cloud/project/altair'])
```

Comment: I suspect that `/cloud/project` is in your `PYTHONPATH` (or `/cloud/project` is your current working directory) and so `/cloud/project/altair` is being interpreted as a namespace when you run `import altair`. Try modifying your path or chaning working directories.

Comment: Thank you Jake, I am trying to modify the path but not sure where to do that.

Comment: @jakevdp I'm adding the link to the file here in case it makes it easier: https://rstudio.cloud/project/2204759

Comment: @FernandoHan You can check your `PYTHONPATH` variable with `Sys.getenv("PYTHONPATH")` and change working directory with `setwd("/my/new/path")`. You could also change the name of the directory you have called `altair` so that it is not picked up by Python instead of the installed library.